# How do I edit a document in a browser and save it to a database?

Tags: html, database, editor

I am trying to write a web based application that allows the user to open a document in a browser window and edit it with some sort of editor such as MS Word (any editor will work) and then let the user save the document and have it stored in a database. I can get the document open in the browser window, but I don't know how to save it back to the database. Is this possible? The database is on the server side, not the client side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be pretty tricky to do.

You'd probably need a Word macro or something to detect when the file is saved and then process whatever code on your server would be needed to process it.

My advice would be to use an existing browser-based document editor like Google Documents and hook into its API to do whatever database work you need.

Otherwise this will be tiresomely complex (what editors will you support? can you run arbitrary code against a user's machine? what if they're offline? etc).